# Which software can collect the CPU & GPU power consumption data for AMD CPU on Chromebook?

Tags: chrome-os

Like the title, is there anyone who knows which software can collect the CPU & GPU power consumption data for an AMD CPU on Chromebook?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Cog to see which language packs you’re running, your battery level and discharge rate, and Chrome plugins. it help you.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please [edit] the essentials into your text.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually, I need more detailed power data, do you know any software like AMDuProf (this can be run on windows and linux, but not chromebook) can gather the power data for chromebook?